# How do you list only user-created variables in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Is it possible to easily list only user-created variables in PowerShell?  The `get-variable` Cmdlet gives me all the system variables as well which isn't what I'd like sometimes.

For example if I open a new session and do

```
$a=1
$b=2
```

I'd like some variant of `get-variable` that only returns `a` and `b` since they are the only two variables that have been explicitly created in the session.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most of the standard variables can be found in `System.Management.Automation.SpecialVariables`. If you filter out these and a small list of other known variables, you can create a reusable function to get user-defined variables:

```
function Get-UDVariable {
  get-variable | where-object {(@(
    "FormatEnumerationLimit",
    "MaximumAliasCount",
    "MaximumDriveCount",
    "MaximumErrorCount",
    "MaximumFunctionCount",
    "MaximumVariableCount",
    "PGHome",
    "PGSE",
    "PGUICulture",
    "PGVersionTable",
    "PROFILE",
    "PSSessionOption"
    ) -notcontains $_.name) -and `
    (([psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.SpecialVariables').GetFields('NonPublic,Static') | Where-Object FieldType -eq ([string]) | ForEach-Object GetValue $null)) -notcontains $_.name
    }
}

$a = 5
$b = 10
get-udvariable

Name                           Value                                                                                                              
----                           -----                                                                                                              
a                              5     
b                              10
```

**Note**: In the ISE there are two additional standard variables: $psISE and $psUnsupportedConsoleApplications

Comment: I thought about this approach, but it seemed just as weird in the console as anything else. Good work!

Answer (score 6):

You can consider using description, but that would require different syntax when creating variables:

```
New-Variable -Name a -Value 1 -Description MyVars
nv b 2 -des MyVars
Get-Variable | where { $_.Description -eq 'MyVars' }
```

2nd syntax uses aliases/positional parameters to shorten your work.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can personally see to do this, would require an extra step of storing the variables in an array.

One example, just for testing:

```
PS C:\Users\Athomsfere> $myVars = @($a, $b)
PS C:\Users\Athomsfere> Get-Variable -Name myVars

Name                           Value
----                           -----
myVars                         {some, thing}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used some of [@jon Z's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18427474/14905075) great answer and generated a `ProxyCommand` for `Get-Variable`.

```
$MetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command Get-Variable)
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData) | Out-File -FilePath Get-UserVariable.ps1
```

Then I edited it to use the `-Exclude` parameter. This way the new `Get-UserVariable` function works like `Get-Variable` with piping. The code should work in *PowerShell* *5.1*.

I've also taken the liberty to create a `guv` alias as well as removing other popular module variables. Sometimes modules will "pollute" the global variable namespace.

```
function Get-UserVariable {
    [Alias('guv')]
    [CmdletBinding(HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2096711')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]
        ${Name},

        [switch]
        ${ValueOnly},

        [string[]]
        ${Include},

        [string[]]
        ${Exclude},

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        ${Scope}
    )

    begin
    {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
            {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }

            $MiscVar = @(
                'FormatEnumerationLimit'
                'MaximumAliasCount'
                'MaximumDriveCount'
                'MaximumErrorCount'
                'MaximumFunctionCount'
                'MaximumVariableCount'
                'PGHome'
                'PGSE'
                'PGUICulture'
                'PGVersionTable'
                'PROFILE'
                'PSSessionOption'
                'PSGetPath'
                'psEditor'
                <# Oh My Posh Argument Completer Script #>
                '__oh_my_poshCompleterBlock'
                <# gh.exe GitHub CLI Arg Completer #>
                '__ghCompleterBlock'
                <# glow.exe Arg Completer #>
                '__glowCompleterBlock'
                <# VSCode Powershell Editor Services Debug #>
                '__psEditorServices_CallStack'
                <# VMware.PowerCLI variables#>
                'UidUtil'
                <# Remove `global:` for the below two items as the `-Exclude` parameter doesn't work with it #>
                'DefaultVIServer'
                'DefaultVIServers' 
                <# ZLocation Module variables #>            
                'ZLocationPromptScriptBlock'
                <# SqlServer Module variables #>
                'SqlServerConnectionTimeout'
                'SqlServerIncludeSystemObjects'
                'SqlServerMaximumChildItems'
                'SqlServerMaximumTabCompletion'
                <# dbatools/PSFramework - Select-DbaObject #>
                '__PSFramework_SelectParam'
                <# PSKoans Module #>
                'PSKoans_ClearOutputStyle'
                'PSKoans_SetOutputStyle'
                <# Chocolatey Tab Completion Module ( chocolateyProfile.psm1 ) #>
                'ChocolateyTabSettings'
                <# posh-git Module #>
                'GitMissing'
                'GitStatus'
                'GitPromptScriptBlock'
                'GitPromptSettings'
                'GitPromptValues'
                'GitTabSettings'
                'TortoiseGitSettings'
                'VcsPromptStatuses'
                <# gsudo chocolatey tool #>
                'gsudoVerbose'
                'gsudoLoadProfile'
                <# PnP.PowerShell #>
                'WebRequestCounter'
                <# EZOut Module #>
                'EZOut_clearOutputStyle'
                'EZOut_Format-Heatmap'
                'EZOut_Format-Markdown'
                'EZOut_Format-RichText'
                'EZOut_Indent'
                'EZOut_setOutputStyle'
                <# SentinelOneAPI Module #>
                'S1_API_Key'
                'S1_Base_URI'
                'S1_Headers'
                'S1_JSON_Conversion_Depth'
                <# PSWriteHTML #>
                'HTMLIcons'
                <# NTFSSecurity Module #>
                'type_NTFS1' 
                <# Local function variables #>
                'MiscVar'
                'SpecialVarType'
                'SpecialVarFlags'
                'SpecialVar'
                'SpecialVarStr'
                'SpecialVarValue'
                'outBuffer'
                'wrappedCmd'
                'scriptCmd'
                'steppablePipeline'
            )
            $SpecialVarType = 'System.Management.Automation.SpecialVariables'
            $SpecialVarFlags = 'NonPublic,Static' # [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]
            $SpecialVar = [psobject].Assembly.GetType($SpecialVarType).GetFields($SpecialVarFlags)
            $SpecialVarStr = $SpecialVar | Where-Object -Property FieldType -EQ ([string])
            $SpecialVarValue = $SpecialVarStr | ForEach-Object { [WildcardPattern]::Escape( $_.GetValue('') ) }
            $PSBoundParameters['Exclude'] += $MiscVar + $SpecialVarValue + $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Values.Name

            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Get-Variable', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            $scriptCmd = { & $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }

            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    process
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    end
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    <# New clean Block Note:
     # Not available in PowerShell Desktop
     # Not currently used in `Get-Variable` as of 4/4/2023
     #>
    # clean
    # {
    #     if ($null -ne $steppablePipeline) {
    #         $steppablePipeline.Clean()
    #     }
    # }

<#
.ForwardHelpTargetName Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Get-Variable
.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet
#>

}
```